# How to Magento getBaseUrl on Frontend from Backend?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6, base-url

My **frontend url** and **backend url** isn't the same.

example,

> Frontend : http://magento.com/
>
> Backend  : http://my.magento.com/

then,

How to get the **Frontend** base url from **Backend**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a store with customized admin area URL but I guess this shall work:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
```

Comment: Make sure that $storeId is not null. If settings 'Add Store Code to Urls' is set to 'Yes' and if $storeId is null, it will add 'admin' into url.